# std::function and std::bind: how to load a std::bind with a function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I use a function template to load a std::bind obj, my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename RT_, typename ...Args>
void installCallback(const char name[], const std::function<RT_(Args...)> &func)
{

}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    installCallback("add01", std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    installCallback<int, int, int>("add01", std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));// didn't work either

    // this work well
    std::function<int(int, int)> fun = std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    installCallback("add02", fun);
    return 0;
}
```

, I got this error:

> ```
> /home/tong/Documents/awesome_auto_drive/awe_auto/sample/module/main.cpp:20:90: error: no matching function for call to ‘installCallback(const char [6], std::_Bind_helper<false, int (&)(int, int), const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type)’
>    20 |     installCallback("add01", std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)); 
>       |                                                                                          ^
> $./main.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class RT_, class ... Args> void installCallback(const char*, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&&)’
>     6 | void installCallback(const char name[], std::function<RT_(Args...)> &&func)
>       |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> $./main.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> $./main.cpp:20:90: note:   ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, int (&)(int, int), const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type’ {aka ‘std::_Bind<int (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(int, int)>’} is not derived from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’
>    20 |     installCallback("add01", std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
>       |                                                                                          ^
> sample/module/CMakeFiles/module.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'sample/module/CMakeFiles/module.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
> make[2]: *** [sample/module/CMakeFiles/module.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2665: recipe for target 'sample/module/CMakeFiles/module.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [sample/module/CMakeFiles/module.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

who can tell me, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into template function argument deduction rules.  `std::bind` does not return a `std::function`, and your passed `int` for `Args...` is only a prefix to `Args...`.  So C++ attempts to deduce the rest of `Args...` and fails with that error.

A quick fix is

```
template<class Sig>
void installCallback(const char name[], const std::function<Sig> &func)
```

then

```
installCallback<int(int, int)>
```

this leaves the body of `installCallback` bereft of `Args...`.

Now,

```
installCallback("add01", std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

cannot work, because `bind` (a) is not a std function, and (b) doesn't know what its argument types are.

It is also pointless here.

```
installCallback("add01", add);
```

is logically equivalent and less filled with noise.  It still won't compile; however in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) this will:

```
installCallback("add01", std::function(add));
```

due to deduction guides.  The bind version will not.

As a general rule, if you are using std bind, instead use a lambda.  In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) lambdas can replace 95% of bind usage mechanically, and in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) it becomes 99.9%, with the remaining 0.1% being features of bind you probably shouldn't be using and don't know exists (and usually won't until it breaks your code in surprising ways; passing std bind to std bind).

Comment: thanks for your replay, i solved my problem by : `template<class Sig>
void installCallback(const char name[], const std::function<Sig> &func)`，and i knew std::bind return type is std::_Bind, i used try to turn 'std::_Bind' to 'std::function' but i failed. i want to know, should ineed to use std::bind instead of std::function?

Comment: @joet your question is akin to "to deliver my bread, should I use a truck or a road?"  `std::bind` and `std::function` are not alternatives in any meaningful sense.

Comment: it seems that i have much work with this, thanks very much

Comment: Isn't this behaviour of template argument deduction really strange? A reasonable person would assume that if you provide some template arguments for a pack but then deduction for the rest of the pack fails, it should just take the ones you provided as the entire pack. Why doesn't C++ work that way?

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from @yakk-adam-nevraumont. I think it is very clear and explains things aptly; the superior answer so far so I upvoted it. The only other contribution I can make is that I was able to arrive at a similar conclusion (deduction rules not yielding `std::function`) using the boost library to de-mangle the printed type names of each expression. See code below modified from the sample @JoeT provided and working snippet [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1Mqj8E).

You'll notice the deduced type of `fun1` is different than the explicit type of `fun2`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

template<typename RT_, typename ...Args>
void installCallback(const char name[], const std::function<RT_(Args...)> &func)
{

}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto fun1 = std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    std::function<int(int, int)> fun2 = std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    char const* name = typeid( fun1 ).name();

    // Outputs: std::_Bind<int (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(int, int)>
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(fun1).name()) << std::endl;

    // Outputs: std::function<int (int, int)>
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(fun2).name()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```