# Why is this `my::test` not deduced template parameter?

Tags: c++, g++, variadic-templates, clang++, template-argument-deduction

I had a problem similar to this one: [std::function and std::bind: how to load a std::bind with a function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620865/stdfunction-and-stdbind-how-to-load-a-stdbind-with-a-function-template)

I didn't find any satisfactory answer, but my doubt is similar (not the same) as this post above

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

namespace my {
  template <typename T>
  struct test;

  template <typename R, typename ...Ts>
  struct test<R(Ts...)>{    
    test(R(*func)(Ts...)){
       //None content, only test
    }
  };
}

void install1(my::test<int(int, int)> func)
{

}

template <typename R, typename ...Ts>
void install2(my::test<R(Ts...)> func)
{

}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    install1(add);

    my::test<int(int, int)> fun = add;
    install1(fun);

    install2<int, int, int>(add);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Problems I've noticed:

- When calling the install 2 function, the parameters cannot be deducted
- If I use in `void install2` this code

  ```
  template <typename R, typename A, typename B>
  void install2(my::test<R(A, B)> func)
  {}

  install2<int, int, int>(add);
  ```

  This code above works fine, but if i remove "A, B" and put "...Ts" the program doesn't compile

Thank in advance, and I apologize for any misunderstanding in the description of the problem (I'm using google translate)

Comment: Your code compiles if I replace `install2<int, int, int>(add);` with `install2<int, int, int>({add});`

Comment: Strange, why ({add}) works and (&add) not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
template <typename R, typename ...Ts>
void install2(my::test<R(Ts...)> func)
```

and calling

```
install2<int, int, int>(add);
```

you have provided explicit template arguments for the first template parameter and two elements of the parameter pack. But there could still be more elements in the pack. Therefore the function parameter still has a type containing template parameters that need to be deduced (basically `my::test<int(int, int, Ts...)>`).

So template argument deduction will be applied to the argument/parameter pair and it will fail, because the function argument you are providing does not have a `my::test` type.

With

```
template <typename R, typename A, typename B>
void install2(const char name[], my::test<R(A, B)> func)
```

you have provided template arguments to all template parameters explicitly, so `my::test<R(A, B)> func` will not be a deduced context anymore.

As mentioned in the comments to the question `install2<int, int, int>({add});` also works because the braces make the function argument/parameter pair a non-deduced context.

---

If you want to be able to call the function with explicit template arguments and without braces, you can make the function parameter always a non-deduced context, for example using C++20's `std::type_identity`:

```
template <typename R, typename ...Ts>
void install2(std::type_identity_t<my::test<R(Ts...)>> func)
```

However, then it is not possible anymore to call it *without* an explicit template argument list.

You could use both this version and the original as overloads, forwarding one to the other, to cover all situations you mention in your example code.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work, that is, there may be more arguments (int, int, Ts..), but why using initializer_list ({}) or type_identity_t makes it work correctly?
From what I've seen, type_identity_t just defines the type (using type = T), shouldn't they be semantically the same?

Comment: @LUCASPAIXÃOSOARESRIBEIRO Both of these cause the function parameter to become a so-called _non-deduced context_. In a non-deduced context template argument deduction is not done. They are non-deduced contexts because the language rules state that they are. In the case of braces it is simply because braces have no type, so deduction wouldn't make any sense. In the case of `std::type_identity_t<T>` it is a trick, because that is an alias expanding to `std::type_identity<T>::type` and in this form it wouldn't be possible to deduce `T`, because `::type` could be any type for any `T`.

Comment: @LUCASPAIXÃOSOARESRIBEIRO https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts The relevant items applying here are 6) for the braces and 1) for the `std::type_identity` trick.